# Xcode 7 iOS 9 Swift 2.0 Spritekit performance is slow

Tags: swift2, xcode7, ios9

I had a sprite kit based game running fine on iOS8, however when testing the app on the iOS 9 beta 5 and it is jerky and quite slow.

So I installed the xcode 7 and recompiled the app in swift 2.0, but it is still very slow and jerky.

Is anybody else having this issue? an ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I'm using CoreImage with OpenGL and it became very slow when compiling with iOS 9, but in my case, it was fast compiled with ios8 and running on iOS 9 device..

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you were able to resolve your problem, but I've been experiencing a lot of lagging with Swift2.0 and XCode7 - smh (9/23/15)

Here is what I did:

1. Clean your derived data for your project. Not just the content but the folder that contains the Derived data;
2. Go to *Build Settings*;
3. Click *All* ;
4. Search for *Whole* (Optimization Levels should come up)
5. Check *Fast Module Optimization* for debug and release.

I am seeing a huge performance increase. However, I'm still testing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My app that uses GLKit always ran above 40fps in iOS 8 and dropped to less than 10fps in iOS 9.

To fix it I started a new project in xcode 7 and dragged all the files accross from the existing project. Desperate times called for desperate measures but now it runs perfectly in iOS 9.

Probably not a viable solution for most people but it worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately that was not a resolution for me.  To drop into single digits fps from a solid 55?  What must have been changed in the internals?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  It turns out that it was because I was using multiple SKViews in my app.  I didn't have noticeable issues in iOS 8, but then they got much worse in iOS 9.  Fortunately there is a good technical article put out by Apple that outlines what to do for multiple SKViews in different view controllers.  When I implemented this performance went back up to 60FPS:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1889/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be using SKLightNode?  If so try removing all light node's from your code.  I did this and my game is running back at 60fps like it did in iOS8.  This is just one of the issues that SpritKit has in iOS 9 and it's become a sore subject on the Apple Forums with little feedback from Apple.  Try going through the forums if SKLightNode isn't the problem in your game: https://forums.developer.apple.com/welcome.

Source:[SKLightNode performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320450/sklightnode-performance-issues)

Answer (score 0):

I posted one possible solution to this here:
[My Xcode 7.3 compiler is constantly breaking and causing extremely long Build and Compile times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38404385/my-xcode-7-3-compiler-is-constantly-breaking-and-causing-extremely-long-build-an)

The problem for me was that I used Emojis for variable names and `.swift` file names.

I would recommend that you attempt to open and save your project in a free version of **AppCode** which is how I was able to diagnose the Emoji problem by checking to see how AppCode behaves with the same project.