# My Xcode 7.3 compiler is constantly breaking and causing extremely long Build and Compile times

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

**This Issue Occurred On A SpriteKit Xcode Project**

I have an issue with Swift where, once my project reaches a certain level of complexity where I have tons of classes and methods around, my autocompletion breaks so that "Jump To Definition" ceases to work and my IDE is reduced to the usefulness of a basic TextEditor/Notepad.

My code's color will change to white completely, which causes a lot of strain on my eyes, and this seems to only happen when I remove and add large blocks of code as I watch my CPU activity climb up to 75% usage on all CPU cores.

I think this started happening when I switched the target iOS from 9.3 over to 8.0. Is this an issue with the compiler trying to interpret old Swift syntax?

I also will have cases where I wait two minutes for minor changes to compile, only for the build to fail due to "Linker command failed with exit code", which is easily fixed by compiling twice.

Here's my specs:

OS X 10.11.4

Core i7 Skylake 4.0GHz

16 GB DDR4 RAM

256GB SSD

I'm thinking about building a system running OS X with dual processors which might alleviate the issue, since it can take upwards of 2 minutes just to compile code that's different by 1 line.

Comment: Did you file a bug report with Apple? — Also, are you using the toolchain? This behavior is downright normal with Xcode 7.3 and a downloaded Swift toolchain.

Comment: I started and wrote Swift since day one, even find my way to release an app wrote with Swift 1.0 beta before Apple even allows it. But end up gave up using it on important projects. Although it's getting better and better, and Apple is dedicated to make it the major player, it's still way too "new" compares to Objective-C. Yes it has many advantages but overall I don't feel like it worth the trouble as Apple changes the syntax way too often and break things constantly. With a quad-core iMac with 24GB RAM, I still feel Xcode is slow on Objective-C, not to mention Swift.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found one solution which resolved my issue.

**Remove All Emojis From Variable Names & .Swift File Names**

Contrary to Apple's official Swift 2.0 textbook, DO NOT use ANY kind of Emoji's for things like **Variable Names** and **Swift File Names** UNLESS you know that the emoji you're using is a very old emoji *(but even then, I wouldn't recommend it)*.

After opening my project in AppCode, AppCode had unicode problems with file names such as: `foobar.swift`. It was very buggy and it would break Xcode later if I opened and saved a project with pre-existing emojis in AppCode.

So avoid using emojis in your code unless it's for strings like:

```
let someString = "⬛️"
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Swift! Great language, awful tooling.

Joking aside, there are a couple of issues at play here. First off, syntax highlighting disappears when SourceKit crashes. SourceKit is the library which parses Swift on-the-fly so that Xcode can do things like indexing, syntax highlighting and code completion. It's a lot better than it used to be (using Swift 1.0 in Xcode was almost comical at times), but it's still far from perfect. Until SourceKit improves, you won't see much difference.

As for your build times, it's worth trying something like the [Swift Build Time Analyzer](https://github.com/RobertGummesson/BuildTimeAnalyzer-for-Xcode) to see which functions are taking a particularly long time to compile. I recently halved the compile time of the project I work on by removing all lazy vars set via closures. A recent compiler change made type inference for these sorts of closures incredibly slow, so each one was taking ~6 seconds to compile.